# iCloud storage entitlements and Jailbreak

Tags: ios, jailbreak, icloud

I'm trying to use `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` inside my app and it works as expected with a non-jailbroken iPad. I can delete the app and when I reinstall it, the preferences are still stored in iCloud.

However, when I try to run the same app in a jailbroken iPhone (AppSync for iOS 5.0+ installed), I get the following error:

```
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error: com.companyname.yourapp has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement
```

I tried the common fixes as recreating and reinstalling provisioning profiles or cleaning the build directory, but there's no way to fix the issue.

On the other hand, I know that development with Game Center + jailbroken device with AppSync leads to 'Game not recognized' errors.

Do you know if iCloud storage development and jailbreak can lead to this error I'm getting?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to reply my own question, and if you have Jailbreak + AppSync for iOS 5.0+ installed, iCloud doesn't work as expected. You must delete AppSync.